# Pandas: datareader unable to get historical stock data

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, datareader, google-finance, pandas-datareader

I found that some of the stock exchanges is not supported for datareader. Example, Singapore. Any workaround?
`query = web.DataReader(("SGX:BLA"), 'google', start, now)` return such error`

`IOError: after 3 tries, Google did not return a 200 for url 'http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=SGX%3ABLA&startdate=Jan+01%2C+2015&enddate=Apr+20%2C+2016&output=csv`

It works for IDX indonesia
`query = web.DataReader(("IDX:CASS"), 'google', start, now)`

Answer (score 0):

That URL is a 404 - pandas isn't at fault, maybe just check the URL? Perhaps they're on different exchanges with different google finance support.

Comment: thanks for your reply. With the same link provided by datareader, they are exchanges that is supported and working fine, london, frankfrut, amsterdam, Indonesia and Johannesburg. I know datareader is mean for US stocks as I do not see people discuss about getting historical data for other stocks exchanges. The problem is if you do it manually thru google link, you can get the csv. example [link] https://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=SGX%3ABLA&ei